# Parse Query does not retrive me updated data from the cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

I have an ParseObject in the cloud database. At the begining this object had an JSONArray that contained 2 JSONObjects. Then I run the next code:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "List lenght: " + new ParseQuery<MyParseObject>("MyParseObject").get("objectId").getJSONArray("MyJSONArray").length(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This show the result: "List lenght: 2". Well, the problem is when I manually delete a JSONObject from that List in the cloud, and later run the same code, the result is the same, but it should be: "List lenght: 1". I can see perfectly that there are only one JSONObject in the JSONArray.
What could happen?

Answer (score 1):

Check once more your table, better on parse account site.
Seams to me, your field looks like [,object]. Thats why you have length of array = 2 but one of your object in array is empty, and you have only one valid JSON object.